# Pipe to multiple files, but not stdout

Tags: bash, stdout, tee

I want to pipe stdout to multiple files, but keep stdout itself quiet. `tee` is close but it prints to both the files and stdout

```
$ echo 'hello world' | tee aa bb cc
hello world
```

This works but I would prefer something simpler if possible

```
$ echo 'hello world' | tee aa bb cc >/dev/null
```

Comment: In `tee aa bb cc`, `tee` has to write 3 files, and you still have `bash` redirecting standard output to a file. In `tee aa bb > cc`, you have the bash redirect, but `tee` only needs to write to 2 files. I'd say the 2nd is more efficient, but only in the strictest sense; you'll never notice the difference.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
echo 'hello world' | tee aa bb > cc
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also close tee stdout output by writing to `/dev/full`

```
echo 'hello world' | tee aa bb cc >/dev/full
```

or by closing stdout.

```
echo 'hello world' | tee aa bb cc >&-
```

Be however aware that you will get either `tee: standard output: No space left on device` or `tee: standard output: Bad file descriptor` warnings.

Comment: `/dev/null`, not `/dev/full`

Comment: Not. it's indeed `/dev/full` so that the pipe is closed. With `/dev/null`, `tee` will still continue to write, even if there is no space left for files `aa`, `bb` and `cc`.

Comment: Won't this make `tee` fail immediately since it will get an error writing to stdout? The rest of the output of the pipe won't be written to the named files.